# Order by the same column twice

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT el.event_title
      ,se.event_eventDateAndTime
FROM events__events_list el
JOIN events__sub_events se ON el.UID = se.event_masterEvent
WHERE (se.event_eventDateAndTime BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 45 DAY))
ORDER BY se.event_eventDateAndTime ASC;
```

This produces a list of events ordered by the date:

| event_title | event_eventDateAndTime |
| --- | --- |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-22 19:30:00 |
| Event 1 | 2023-02-23 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-24 19:30:00 |
| Event 3 | 2023-02-25 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-26 19:30:00 |
| Event 1 | 2023-02-27 19:30:00 |

If I order by event title and event date I get the following:

| event_title | event_eventDateAndTime |
| --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 2023-02-23 19:30:00 |
| Event 1 | 2023-02-27 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-22 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-24 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-26 19:30:00 |
| Event 3 | 2023-02-25 19:30:00 |

But I want to order by the event title and the date, so the events are kept together and then ordered by the date of the first instance... like this:

| event_title | event_eventDateAndTime |
| --- | --- |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-22 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-24 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-26 19:30:00 |
| Event 1 | 2023-02-23 19:30:00 |
| Event 1 | 2023-02-27 19:30:00 |
| Event 3 | 2023-02-25 19:30:00 |

I'm lost and I'm not sure how best to move forward. I've tried searching but I can't find anything that matches my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MIN` window function that selects the minimum "*event_eventDateAndTime*" for each "*event_title*" for you, in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT el.event_title
      ,se.event_eventDateAndTime
FROM       events__events_list el
INNER JOIN events__sub_events se ON el.UID = se.event_masterEvent
WHERE se.event_eventDateAndTime BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 45 DAY)
ORDER BY MIN(event_eventDateAndTime) OVER(PARTITION BY event_title),
         event_title,
         event_eventDateAndTime
```

Output:

| event_title | event_eventDateAndTime |
| --- | --- |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-22 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-24 19:30:00 |
| Event 2 | 2023-02-26 19:30:00 |
| Event 1 | 2023-02-23 19:30:00 |
| Event 1 | 2023-02-27 19:30:00 |
| Event 3 | 2023-02-25 19:30:00 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ePejDQvANDFyk8HKpDuLj/0).

Comment: Magic - thank you! This is perfect.